# Sum of products or product of sums?

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

What does P indicate in this expression?
`F(A,B,C,D) = P(4,5,6,7,8,12,13)+d(1,15)`
And does d(1,15) represent don't care condition?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: I would guess it means these are the values for which the function should be Positive (i.e. 1)

Comment: I would guess it's **P**roduct. Which is opposite to what @MikeP is guessing.. but it is definitely should be verified with your textbook/notes.

Comment: In my experience, P can be used for both SOP and POS. What i would do in focus on F(A,B,C,D). The lack of a bar on the F would make me believe that the statement is in SOP format. HOWEVER, when it comes to digital electronics representation, one can be easily confused with semantics, even different text books use different representation. I would consult your main text/notes to see what it exactly means.

Answer (score 1):

The P in this expression is the minterms on Karnaugh Mapping and represents the Sum of Products.

And yes, the d is the don't care terms